# SAPUI5 - HTML5 Application - Use function in manifest.json

Tags: sapui5, manifest.json

I have this really basic SAPUI5 application created from the template available in SAP Business Application Studio.

I have defined a custom resource in the `manifest.json` which executes a javascript function:

```json
{
  "sap.ui5": {
    "resources": {
      "js": [
        {
          "uri": "lib/myFunction.js"
        }
      ],
      "css": [
        {
          "uri": "css/style.css"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "...": "..."
}
```

Is there a way to dynamically define the `resource` to be used in the application bootstrap?

For example, in my "lib" folder, I have different `*.js` files:

[image: My Web IDE SAPUI5 project folder structure]

Is there a way to choose a single `*.js` to be used?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Currently, the question is a bit unclear. Do you expect the `myFunction_n` resources already available in the HTML file when the SAPUI5 bootstraps? Or where exactly are you expecting those functions to be available?

Comment: Btw.: please note that the section `manifest.json` [**`/sap.ui5/resources/js` is deprecated** since UI5 1.94!](https://github.com/SAP/openui5-docs/blob/fe189b93cc1b262f734e0c9565f863765a48a580/docs/Descriptor_for_Applications_Components_and_Libraries_manifest_json_be0cf40.md#note-4) Also [until v1.92, the resources declared in that section load via sync XHR](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/3137) which freezes the browser UI thread during the round trips.

Comment: What would be the use case?

Comment: @Boghyon Hoffmann yes, I expect the myFunction_n resources already available in the HTML file when the SAPUI5 bootstraps

Comment: @Benedikt Kromer use case: following this blog https://blogs.sap.com/2018/07/17/monitoring-a-fiori-launchpad-on-sap-cloud-portal-using-dynatrace./ it is used a js snippet to monitor apps on dynatrace. I want to have different dashboard (--> different js snippets) on dynatrace for the different countries in which the same application is used, so i want to choose dynamically the script.

Comment: Is the UI5 app going to be launched from the Fiori launchpad? Or is it a standalone app?

Comment: @Boghyon Hoffmann, from the FLP, it is an application included inside a Portal Site. So, my previous comment is to be edited in: I expect the myFunction_n resources already available in the Component.js file when the SAPUI5 bootstraps (since the index.html is not read when using FLP)

Comment: is there any progress on this?